ngrok not establishing connection with working localhost
I have a .NET 8 WebAPI running (Kestrel) on localhost port 8080,
I also have an ngrok container running with my authtoken and listening on port 8080 using the following command:

docker run --net=host -it -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=[MyAuthToken] ngrok/ngrok:latest http 8080

The ngrok container is running fine according to the ngrok log screen:
ngrok                                                                                         (Ctrl+C to quit)                                                                                                              Help shape K8s Bindings https://ngrok.com/new-features-update?ref=k8s

Session Status                online
Account                       nativ bashari (Plan: Free)
Update                        update available (version 3.15.1, Ctrl-U to update)
Version                       3.15.0
Region                        Europe (eu)
Latency                       62ms
Web Interface                 http://0.0.0.0:4040
Forwarding                    https://3100-77-124-51-65.ngrok-free.app -> http://localhost:8080

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00      

The WebAPI is also running and accessible on port 8080. However, when I try a GET request through the ngrok gateway, like:
https://3100-77-124-51-65.ngrok-free.app/api/MyController

I receive a "502 Bad Gateway" error. Here are the screenshots of the error:
ngrok endpoint error screen
ngrok log screen
After extensive troubleshooting,
I would appreciate help from anyone who has experienced a similar issue or knows how to resolve this.
I have already added a CORS policy to accept inbound requests.
And reset the ngrok container.

This appears to be a classic localhost in a container means that container, not the host it is running on issue.
If you're using Docker Desktop you can use host.docker.internal to get to the actual host. Other container runtimes have similar magic names.
